# Moving girlfriend with me from US to UK - visas?

Tags: united-kingdom

I may be moving from the US to the London for a job offer and I'd like my girlfriend to come with me.  We would live there for a few years at least, so she'd like to find a job there.  What options are available for this situation regarding visas?  Should I tell my company about her, hoping they'll help?  We don't want to get married, but have lived together for a while so I consider it a substantive relationship.  We're both US citizens.

Comment: What kind of visa do you have?

Comment: Have you been living together for atleast two years? Can you prove it? If so, you may qualify as unmarried partners. It only matters if the UK considers it a 'substantive relationship'. That affects everything, even her ability to just visit you later on if she can't move there with you.

Comment: As far as the UK company is concerned, your personal relationship really isn't their business and they could care less. They are her visas, so she has to sort that stuff out. If you decide to make this a negotiating point (something that would be very unusual for the UK), then that is strictly between you and the company wanting to hire you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not married, she will have to get a general visitors visa. If your company is paying for housing/ relocation, I believe that you must tell them your situation. They are NOT LIKELY to help financially, but they may be able to give you some more information about the transition with a domestic partner.

I believe the visa will be good for up to six months, but during her stay, she will NOT be able to work there.

Comment: She cannot come to the UK as a 'visitor' if she is in reality just living with her partner. She will almost certainly be refused entry and complicate future entry into the UK.

Comment: This is not true; as mentioned in comments, dependant visas can be granted to unmarried partners under certain circumstances (at least two years living together, no impediment to marriage under UK law, etc).